# IExtensibleDataObject used in Clipboard

Tags: c#, wcf, clipboard

I'm using a WCF service with a net.tcp endpoint. 
I have implemented the `IExtensibleDataObject` interface on all my DTO's to have forward compatible clients.
For that I map the ExtensionData property of my DTO's to my corresponding Model classes and then when sending a call back to the client the information remains intact.
Because my application is able to have multiple parallel running instances I've to persist the `ExtensionDataObject` throughout a Copy/Paste operation from one client instance to another.

The problem is now that if i try to map the model to a representation in the clipboard I have to also map the ExtensionData property to the clipboard object but that doesn't work because the ExtensionDataObject isn't Serializable..
I always get the CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA error when pasting from clipboard.

Is there any possibility?

Comment: Why don't you just use XML serialisation and place the XML on the clipboard? The extension data will be serialized into the XML.

Comment: I don't really  understand what you are asking - why would you use the clipboard etc. You haven't explained that at all.

Comment: I have indeed explained why I have to use the Clipboard.
Because I have to copy data from one instance of the application to another.
Serializing to xml would be a possible solution, that's true.

Comment: Why is **a WCF service** using the clipboard? The clipboard is for GUI applications.

Comment: I do not use the clipboard in the wcf service.
I use the clipboard in my client application which consumes the WCF service and all the DTO's of the WCF service implement the IExtensibleDataObject interface to ensure proper round trip logic.
WCF Service (DTO) is being mapped to a Model (MVVM pattern) and those models are used in the client application.